# SVG height percentage not working under Linux browsers?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

[image: svg height not working]

The exact same code works under Windows with Chrome, FF and IE.
I just switched to Linux and this code doesn't work neither on FF or Chrome?
I tried the "style" tag, with no change in results.
Can someone help?
Is there a browser independent way of having 100% svg coverage?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svgEle" height="100%" width="100%"></svg>
<script>
    var snapCanvas = Snap("#svgEle");
    var circle = snapCanvas.circle(100, 100, 100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code? Fiddle? Something?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser is behaving correctly.  If you try the HTML on Windows Chrome you get the same result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="svgEle" height="100%" width="100%">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason is as follows:

1. You haven't specified an actual size for the SVG. You've told it to be 100% of it's parent (`<body>`).
2. The `<body>` by default has width 100% and its height collapses to the height of its children.
3. The size of its child (the SVG) is not determinable, so the `<body>` height defaults to the "intrinsic size" used by browsers when it can't determine a size. That height is 150px.
4. So the end result is that the SVG has a size of 100% by 150px.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It reminded me that I didn't have a full HTML document when testing on Windows.
When I remove the <body>  tags, the SVG element is still displaying as it is with them. Somehow the browser adds the <body> tags on its own. But if I remove the <!DOCTYPE html> tag, then the SVG element displays as I expect. Is there a better answer, because without the <!DOCTYPE html> it doesn't matter that the SVG element is inside the body tags or not and it fills the whole window.

Comment: Without a DOCTYPE, the browser uses "quirks" rendering mode.  In quirks mode, one of the things that is different is how percentage heights are calculated. See: https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-percentage-height-calculation-quirk

Comment: But when I change height '100%' to '500%', result is still the same

Comment: @SeyitBilal 500% of what, though?  500% x <indeterminate> is still <indeterminate>. So it will again fall back to the default 150px.